# Lock-free array expansion in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, lock-free

I have an array to which many threads are writing. However each thread has a pre-assigned range of indices which it may write to. Further, nothing will be reading from the array until all threads are done.

So far, so thread-safe. The problem arises when I need to expand the array, by which of course I mean swap it out for a larger array which copies the first. This is only done occasionally (similar to an ArrayList).

Currently I'm acquiring a lock for every single write to the array. Even though there is no need to lock in order to keep the array consistent, I'm having to lock in case the array is currently being copied/swapped.

As there are very many writes I don't want to require a lock for them. I'm okay with a solution which requires locking for writer threads only while the array is being copied and swapped, as this is infrequent.

But I can't just impose write locks only when the copy/swap is in progress, as threads may already be committing writes to the old array.

I think I need some variety of barrier which waits for all writes to complete, then pauses the threads while I copy/swap the array. But CyclicBarrier would require me to know exactly how many threads are currently active, which is non-trivial and possibly susceptible to edge-cases in which   the barrier ends up waiting forever, or lowers itself too early. In particular I'm not sure how I'd deal with a new thread coming in while the barrier is already up, or how to deal with threads which are currently polling a job queue, so will never decrement the barrier count while there are no new jobs.

I may have to implement something which (atomically) counts active threads and tries to pre-empt all the edge cases.

But this may well be a "solved" problem that I don't know about, so I'm hoping there may be a simpler (therefore better) solution than the Cyclic barrier/thread counting. Ideally one which uses an existing utility class.

By the way, I've considered CopyOnWriteArray. This is no use to me, as it copies for every write (a lot of them), not just array expansions.

Also note the structure written to pretty much has to be an array, or array-based.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just give each thread its own array, and copy them into a final array after all the writing is done?

Comment: You could simply use AtomicBoolean compareAndSet while writing, while it returns false (ensure that it does when the copying is taking place) you don't write.

Comment: How does »However each thread has a pre-assigned range of indices which it may write to« and »The problem arises when I need to expand the array« go together? What happens to the pre-assigned range of indices? If you only add new "slots", why not implement a class which keeps many arrays and adds new ones as needed?

Comment: Can you replace the 1d array by a 2d array? If you need to access it in 1d format you could write a wrapper class that maps 1d indices to 2d indices.

Comment: @tgdavies Threads are from an executor's pool and do one job at a time after picking up a new job, each job has a reservation item reservation item. Most of the time the reservation item is for a single row, only occasionally a range.. So I simplified when I said each thread has its "own range": that range will change for each job the thread picks up.

Comment: @joy A writer could already be in the process of writing when the expansion takes place. So it would carry on writing to the old array and what it wrote wouldn't ever reach the new array. Setting a lock flag would be shutting the stable door after the horse has (possibly) bolted;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's technically not correct, you can probably use a [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html). The threads that are writing to a single portion all use a read lock (this is the technically incorrect part, they're not reading...), and the resize uses a write lock. That way, all writing threads can work together. A resize has to wait until all portioned writes are done, which then blocks the entire array. Once that is done, all portioned writes can continue.

Comment: Arguably they really are "reading" and "writing" - they're reading the array *reference*, and writing a new array *reference*. The fact that all of them are writing to the referred array is somewhat immaterial :)

Comment: There's nothing "technically not correct" about using `ReadWriteLock` in that way. If there's any problem, it's that "ReadWriteLock" is a bad name. "SharedExclusiveLock" would be better. The `readLock()` object grants the caller _shared access_ to the protected data, and the `writeLock()` object grants _exclusive access._ In many applications, if a thread only wants shared access, that's because it will only read the data. But, as OP's question proves, there can be other safe ways to share access.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution, although there will be some overhead, but no locking.

But first, I would recommend using a 2-D array (an array of arrays) unless you absolutely need a 1-D array. You can then expand the top-level array without affecting the contents of the lower-level arrays. You can also write a wrapper class for this to access the whole thing using 1-D indices if you wish.

But if you *really* want to have a 1-D array, I would recommend the following:

I am assuming each thread has some number which it knows which uniquely identifies itself and can be converted to a small index (else, I don't see how you index into the main array).

I also assume you have a reference to the main array called `mainArray` which is a statically accessible, but it also could be injected into the threads. It should be declared volatile.

You need another array `currentArrays` of length `numberOfThreads`, also available to all of the threads. Each array element will contain a reference of the main array the thread is currently using.

When you need to grow the array, allocate a new array and write its reference to `mainArray`. You don't need to copy anything at this point.

Before accessing the main array in your threads you need to grab a local reference to it (i.e., a local variable) by assigning from `mainArray`.

Then compare the grabbed reference with the reference in `currentArrays`. If it is the same, carry on, being careful to use the local reference.

If it is different, call a method (that you will write) to copy the part of the previous array for your thread to the new array and then carry on as before. Write the new array reference to `currentArrays` for that thread. Again, use the local reference until you are done.

The old array should be garbage collected once all of the threads have finished copying their part of it, which means not until all threads have had at least one request requiring it.

There will be some initialisation code for first time use which should be obvious (all `currentArrays` elements are set to `mainArray`).

I believe this should work. There is obviously the overhead of comparing array references before you can access the array; however, if you do a lot of array accesses in a single transaction/request you can save the array reference that you grabbed, pass it around and only recheck when you need to grab it again. That should reduce the overhead.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested it. Comments welcome.

Comment: The variables don’t have to be static, they just need to be accessible by the worker threads. An explanation of an algorithm should not mandate such a technical detail. Besides that, there doesn’t seem to be a need for the `previousArray` variable at all. In your description, it is written but never read. Further, there is a final step missing: once it has been detected that all worker threads finished, a last pass over the `currentArrays` should be made, to check whether all worker threads have seen the final array before terminating. Otherwise, that particular part has to be copied.

Comment: @Holger: Thanks for the comment. You are right about `previousArray`. I missed that. I will amend the answer. In terms of whether the array fields need to be static, `currentArrays` doesn't have to be. I was thinking that the switch over `mainArray` would need to be atomic (as it often does in these lockless solutions), but actually, I think it doesn't. So both of these values could be injected into the threads somehow.